# Yii2 Url home без слеша

Tags: yii2, url

Как вернуть url сайта без слеша на конце ? Url::home возвращает со слешем на конце

```
Url::home(true)
```

> http:://site.com/

А как получить

> http:://site.com

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
Url::base(true);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.